# Smart Client over web services to replace ADO.net

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, ado.net

My company wants to minimize number of connection to a database. For this reason, they want to develop a smart server which will handle smart clients.
Now I have to come up with such an application which can connect to a database and then it will read data from database and give it back to the client (Hence the applications will connect to a web service, not directly to the database).

I want to make the existing huge applications currently using ADO.net classes to use this smart client application. So the solution is to make another ADO.net class which is eventually using web services instead of database directly.
Functions are supposed to response with objects like DbDataReader.

What is the best method to achieve this if I am working in C#?
Can I use WCF to achieve this?
Is there anything ready-made for Oracle services?

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use WCF at the service layer to talk to the smart clients. One question though, do these smart clients talk over the internet or the network (are they on different machines with a centralized database)? If true, then WXF makes sense. Also, you may want to take a look at the Repository abstraction pattern since you seem to be indicating support for multiple databases. Also, I suggest you explore POCOS and Entity Framework. These will help you come up with a good Data Layer and allow you a nice segregation of the Service, Business and Data Layers.

Comment: Thank you Aditya Patil for the answer. Actually the application is way more complex than the one you explained. There is no central database server. Plus there is no cloud configurations for the scattered data sources. On top of that, there are many legacy applications and machines working for the customers so we cannot change whats running overnight.

I will look into what you stated and will try to seek help from it. Thanks again! Cheers!